# Mapping Geography to byte[]: PSQLException: Invalid endian flag value encountered

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to persist an entity with a `Geography(POINT, 4326)` data type. Since Hibernate Spatial doesn't support Geography anyway, I'm using `byte[]` to map it (then JTS to transform).

It works fine when saving the entity the first time, but then I'm loading it again and saving it after updating another property, and getting `Invalid endian flag value encountered` upon the `save()`.

Definition in the entity:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="geography(POINT, 4326)")
private byte[] location;
```

Here's the code which fails on `save()`:

```
task.setProcessed(true);
TaskRepository.save(task);
```

Here's the exception:

```
2014-06-16 10:24:33.740  INFO 10948 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
.....
2014-06-16 10:24:36.859  WARN 10948 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: XX000
2014-06-16 10:24:36.860 ERROR 10948 --- [           main]  o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
2014-06-16 10:24:36.862  INFO 10948 --- [           main]  o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:519)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.save(Unknown Source)
at myapp.backend.Main.processTask(Main.java:75)
    ...

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3281)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
... 17 more

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
... 32 more
```

I'm using Hibernate Core (4.3.1.Final), hibernate-spatial-4.3-SNAPSHOT (I needed SNAPSHOT for some other issue I ran into), with PostgreSQL JDBC driver 9.3-1101-jdbc41 and PostgreSQL 9.3 database w/ PostGIS 2.1.3 on Windows 7 64-bit.

P.S. I've looked at the other stackoverflow questions on this but they relate to mapping to `Geometry` rather than `byte[]`.

Comment: It's a long shot, and I don't even know if you are on Linux, but I had this issue around the time Postgres 9.1 came out and it was to do with old versions of libpq.so being symlinked -- though in my case it arose using pgsql2shp. The solution was to update the symlink, in my case from /usr/bin/libpq.so to point to newer version -- libpq.so.4. There is some info on it here: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1830 Like I say, a long shot, but if you have upgraded at some point from older versions of Postgres/Postgis, conceivable.

Comment: I should have mentioned - I'm actually on Windows 7. But thanks.

Comment: I don't see the string "Invalid endian flag value encountered" in the PgJDBC sources.

Comment: Is this related? https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16778

Comment: Craig - perhaps it comes from PostGIS or from the back-end itself?

Comment: Mike, I set the config property and restarted PostgreSQL but no difference.